# scrapy - parsing items that are paginated

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a url of the form:

```
example.com/foo/bar/page_1.html
```

There are a total of 53 pages, each one of them has ~20 rows.

I basically want to get all the rows from all the pages, i.e. ~53*20 items.

I have working code in my parse method, that parses a single page, and also goes one page deeper per item, to get more info about the item:

```
  def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    restaurants = hxs.select('//*[@id="contenido-resbus"]/table/tr[position()>1]')

    for rest in restaurants:
      item = DegustaItem()
      item['name'] = rest.select('td[2]/a/b/text()').extract()[0]
      # some items don't have category associated with them
      try:
        item['category'] = rest.select('td[3]/a/text()').extract()[0]
      except:
        item['category'] = ''
      item['urbanization'] = rest.select('td[4]/a/text()').extract()[0]

      # get profile url
      rel_url = rest.select('td[2]/a/@href').extract()[0]
      # join with base url since profile url is relative
      base_url = get_base_url(response)
      follow = urljoin_rfc(base_url,rel_url)

      request = Request(follow, callback = parse_profile)
      request.meta['item'] = item
      return request


  def parse_profile(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    # item['address'] = figure out xpath
    return item
```

The question is, how do I crawl each page?

```
example.com/foo/bar/page_1.html
example.com/foo/bar/page_2.html
example.com/foo/bar/page_3.html
...
...
...
example.com/foo/bar/page_53.html
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have two options to solve your problem. The general one is to use `yield` to generate new requests instead of `return`. That way you can issue more than one new request from a single callback. Check the second example at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#basespider-example.

In your case there is probably a simpler solution: Just generate the list of start urs from a patter like this:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    start_urls = ['http://example.com/foo/bar/page_%s.html' % page for page in xrange(1,54)]
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks so much for this. The LinkExtractor on scrapy's site didn't work for me. This did.

Comment: how to check if page is not found. it has only 53 pages. but if I call `xrange(1,60)`.

Comment: In python 3 `xrange()` was renamed to `range()`.

Answer (score 12):

You could use the CrawlSpider instead of the BaseSpider and use SgmlLinkExtractor to extract the pages in the pagination.

For instance:

```
start_urls = ["www.example.com/page1"]
rules = ( Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="next_page"]',))
                , follow= True),
          Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="foto_imovel"]',))
                , callback='parse_call')
    )
```

The first rule tells scrapy to follow the link contained in the xpath expression, the second rule tells scrapy to call the parse_call to links contained in the xpath expression, in case you want to parse something in each page.

For more info please see the doc: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider

Comment: I encounterd a similar problem, what I did is as you said, yet it still just crawl only the start_url page.

Comment: SgmlLinkExtractors and all other classes in the contrib module raises errors.Please use LinkExtracor class instead.

Answer (score 10):

There can be two use cases for 'scrapy - parsing items that are paginated'.

**A). We just want to move across the table and fetch data. This is relatively straight forward.**

```py
class TrainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "trip"
    start_urls = ['somewebsite']
    def parse(self, response):
        ''' do something with this parser '''
        next_page = response.xpath("//a[@class='next_page']/@href").extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Observe the last 4 lines. Here

1. We are getting the next page link form next page xpath from the 'Next' pagination button.
2. if condition to check if its not the end of the pagination.
3. Join this link (that we got in step 1) with the main url using url join
4. A recursive call to the `parse` call back method.

**B)Not only we want to move across pages, but we also want to extract data from one or more links in that page.**

```py
class StationDetailSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'train'
    start_urls = [someOtherWebsite]
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[@class='next_page']"), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"/trains/\d+$"), callback='parse_trains')
    )
    def parse_trains(self, response):
    '''do your parsing here'''
```

Overhere, observe that:

1. We are using the `CrawlSpider` subclass of the `scrapy.Spider` parent class
2. We have set to 'Rules'

   a) The first rule, just checks if there is a 'next_page' available and follows it.

   b) The second rule requests for all the links on a page that are in the format, say `/trains/12343` and then calls the `parse_trains` to perform and parsing operation.
3. **Important**: Note that we don't want to use the regular `parse` method over here as we are using `CrawlSpider` subclass. This class also has a `parse` method so we don't want to override that. Just remember to name your call back method something other than `parse`.