# Getting scrapy to follow specific links on a page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape lyrics from The Original Hip Hop Lyrics Archive.

I've managed to write a spider that scrapes the lyrics of an artist if I release it on the artist page such as this: http://www.ohhla.com/anonymous/aesoprck/.

but when I release it on this page with links to different artist pages http://www.ohhla.com/all.html I get nothing.

This is the rule that I'm trying to use to follow the links to artist pages:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//pre/a/@href',)), follow= True)
```

and this is the rule I'm trying to use to follow the links to different pages with links to the artist pages:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//h3/a/@href',)), follow= True)
```

I modified the tutorial in Scrapy to get this to work since for some reason it didn't work when I started a new project.

Here is my complete working example of the spider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class ohhlaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ohhla"
    download_delay = 0.5
    allowed_domains = ["ohhla.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.ohhla.com/anonymous/aesoprck/"]
    rules = (Rule (LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//h3/a/@href',)), follow= True), # trying to follow links to pages with more links to artist pages
             Rule (LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//pre/a/@href',)), follow= True), # trying to follow links to artist pages
             Rule (LinkExtractor(deny_extensions=("txt"),restrict_xpaths=('//ul/li',)), follow= True), # succeeding in following links to album pages
             Rule (LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//ul/li',)), callback="extract_text", follow= False),) # succeeding in extracting lyrics from the songs on album pages

    def extract_text(self, response):
        """ extract text from webpage"""
        string = response.xpath('//pre/text()').extract()[0]
        with open("lyrics.txt", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(string)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`restrict_xpaths` should not point to the `@href` attribute. It should point to the place where the link extractor would search for links:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//h3'), follow=True)
```

Note that you can specify it as a string instead of a tuple.

---

You can also `allow` all the links having `all*.html` in it:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'all.*?\.html'), follow=True)
```

---

You should also make sure your spider is actually visiting that  "Parent Directory" page. Starting crawling with it sounds logical since this is an index page for the catalog:

```
start_urls = ["http://www.ohhla.com/all.html"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The part two this answer can be useful for crawling specific links in a webpage. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40146522/4418897