# Scrapy - Pagination with ajax

Tags: ajax, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy framework. And I am just learning Python language. I need to scrape data from the online shop. But there is pagination with ajax on some pages. I have watched some tutorials about how to add pagination in a scrapy spider, but it's not clear for me. I know that I need to reproduce requests. I found out these requests in Dev tools---Network tab(please see the photo).

[Link to the shop](https://ddaudio.com.ua/volkswagen-passat-b5-1997-2005__hrom-nakladki.html)

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raj7P.jpg)

I don't know which (Scrapy framework) methods or requests I can use. Could you help me to solve this issue please?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847965/scrapy-parsing-items-that-are-paginated AND https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9Nni6G-iOc . Hope you will get a clue.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html